# Changing to 3rd party mail server

Tags: cpanel, webmail, mx-record, roundcube

I am using a linux hosting. But want to use 3rd party mail server. So if i change the mx record,spf and dkim will my existing webmail link stop working ?

Or I can still check my old emails in the old webmail link ?

Answer (score 0):

The old mails will reside where they were until you migrate them to new third party servers. Your existing webmail link will serve only old mails if they are not migrated. After you change the MX record the mails will be delivered to different system which will be access through new webmail link only.